# Logman user switch confusion

Tags: powershell, performance-monitoring, perfmon, credentials, logman

I'm setting up a powershell script that installs a logman counter on several servers that are in dire need of some performance monitoring.

The documentation states that the -u switch works with **create update, start, stop, delete and query**. [Referenced documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490956.aspx)
However when I try to run most of these with the -u switch I get the error

> Argument 'u' is not allowed with the other arguments specified.

When running logman *parameter* /? I came to the conclusion that the only switches that allow for the -u parameter are the **update create and delete** switches.

My worry is that when rolling this out, I'll have problems passing the user credentials when starting querying and stopping the counters. Because remote access is going to be restricted I have to be able to pass a user that was given the correct credentials, without running my powershell session as that user. (I am not joined to the domain)

Is there anything I'm missing? Perhaps regarding this conflicting documentation?

Comment: -u is a Switch to specify the user credentials to use for cmd execution if not the current user. Create, Update, Start, etc are Verbs (not switches) to control the action of the command. http://pastebin.com/mt1Z7WPS You should not do: "-u Create". Please provide an example of exactly how you are invoking the command.